# Converting alphanumeric values to numeric values in a Python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numeric, alphanumeric

```
   Timestamp CAN ID  Byte DATA[0] DATA[1] DATA[2] DATA[3] DATA[4]  \
1693260  1.478200e+09   0000   8.0      00      00      00      00      00   
732574   1.478199e+09   0000   8.0      00      00      00      00      00   
602503   1.478199e+09   02c0   8.0      14      00      00      00      00   
65525    1.478198e+09   0430   8.0      00      00      00      00      00   
1659292  1.478200e+09   0440   8.0      ff      00      00      00      ff   
46083    1.478198e+09   0002   8.0      00      00      00      00      00   
386324   1.478199e+09   0329   8.0      0c      bc      7f      14      11   
625751   1.478199e+09   0130   8.0      11      80      00      ff      0e   
1647482  1.478200e+09   0002   8.0      00      00      00      00      00   
1403442  1.478200e+09   0000   8.0      00      00      00      00      00   

        DATA[5] DATA[6] DATA[7]      AttackType  
1693260      00      00      00      DoS Attack  
732574       00      00      00      DoS Attack  
602503       00      00      00  Normal Message  
65525        00      00      00  Normal Message  
1659292      d2      08      00  Normal Message  
46083        06      01      a2  Normal Message  
386324       20      00      14  Normal Message  
625751       80      0b      e7  Normal Message  
1647482      03      09      2b  Normal Message  
1403442      00      00      00      DoS Attack
```

Most values in my dataframe are alphanumeric. How do i change the alphabeths in the alphanumeric values to numeric values?

I tried changing the alphanumeric values to nan values and dropping the rows but that didn't work because almost every row in the dataframe contained alphanumeric values. Please help

Comment: Sorry I'm not understanding, do you have an expected output you could share? Could you give an example of what you'd like to achieve?

Comment: It looks like the DATA[x] columns have code numbers in hexadecimal as strings. And if so these can be readily converted to decimal integers.

Comment: I have a dataframe where most values are either letter and number like `d1` or letters like `ff`. I want to change the letters in those values by changing them to their number equivalent. Like `characters = ['a''b''c''d''e''f''g''h''i''j''k''l''m''n''o''p''q''r''s''t''u''v''w''x''y''z']
numbers =['0''1''2''3''4''5''6''7''8''9''10''11''12''13''14''15''16''17''18''19''20''21''22''23''24''25']`. The values should change to `31` instead of `d1` or `55` instead of `ff`

Comment: Are you sure you have letters beyond `f'? The values certainly look like hex code strings from some sort of logging system - in which case ff would be 255 in decimal and d1 would be 209.

Answer (score 0):

Your `CAN ID` and `DATA[0]` ... `DATA[7]` columns are very likely hexadecimal numbers, you can convert them to decimal with:

```py
df = ... # get DataFrame

cols = ['DATA[0]', 'DATA[1]', 'DATA[2]', 'DATA[3]']  # list of columns to convert
df[cols] = df[cols].applymap(int, base=16)           # do conversion
```

(Note this does **not** match the interpretation of these columns in your comment, if you are certain on that interpretation then the solution will be very similar, just pass your own function into `applymap` )

Comment: I believe the title of the first col is missing (presumably it's the index), as the second col looks very much like the timestamp, making `CAN ID` the third column, and that looks very much like hex to me...

Comment: You are right about the second col being timestamp. It would probably be better if the OP converted it to datetime; it looks like a logging record at 1 microsecond intervals.